# Extra white space above Google CSE?

Tags: google-custom-search

I have a Google Site Search worked into this site, and its rendering results about 300 pixels too low. I can use a tool like CSSEDIT, override and edit Google style sheet adjusting the following style:

```
.gsc-results {
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  width : 99%;
  margin-top: -300px;
}
```

Adding the margin line fixes my issue. However, the stylesheet is hosted at Google. I've tried added this style in multiple places to perhaps catch this style setting last and override the other. Doesn't work for me anywhere.

http://www.bankoflabor.com/searchresults.php?q=banking

Perhaps someone can HELP me? Thanks!!

Comment: Try to make it with 2 css classes : `.gsc-webResult.gsc-result`